# Magento Stock (Configurable, Bundle)

Tags: magento, bundle, stock, configurable

I have a website made with Magento, and a theme by me. The problem is:

The simple product with low stock is associated to a configurable product, and when i try to add a higher quantity of that simple product, it allows, and then, after the checkout proccess, we receive a e-mail from the store that there is a failure in the proccess like:

*Payment operation failed: 


Reason:

Not all products are available in the requested quantity*

It occurs in bundle products that have a default quanity more than 1 too.

Someone can help me?

Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Found this solution but i can't truncate my sales tables on database. I have all my sales records there, and there are a lot of them. I can't loose it. [Magento: After ordering configurable product, its canceled because its out of stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161035/magento-after-ordering-configurable-product-its-canceled-because-its-out-of-st?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

How many orders do you need to remove? If you got a handful that you can count by hand, you can try this solution to remove unwanted orders.

[how can i delete test order from magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526914/how-can-i-delete-test-order-from-magento)

It looks like it should work, but, as always, review the code and try it on one order first..

Comment: I don't need to remove orders, i need to know what happens that the customers can add more "Products" in the cart than i have.